# Leitura de csv java

Tags: java

Bem estou precisando fazer um trabalho da faculdade, onde tenho q ler um csv e printar seus dados na tela.
Estou usando o método split para armazenar as informações da linha em um vetor de String, e depois seto todos os dados e uma classe, porem com estou filtrando por "," o arquivo as vezes da pau pois aparecem linhas com essa

> 0.0594,1921,0.982,['Sergei Rachmaninoff', 'James Levine', 'Berliner Philharmoniker'],0.279,831667,0.211,0.0,4BJqT0PrAfrxzMOxytFOIz,0.878,10,0.665,-20.09 6,1.0,"[Piano Concerto No. 3 in D Minor, Op. 30: III. Finale. Alla breve]",4,1921,0.0366,80.954

Resumindo oque esta entre "," e uma posição do array, ou seja oq esta entre colchetes tem q ser apenas uma posição do array ignorando as "," de dentro dos colchetes e n estou consiguindo fazer esse filtro.

Esse é meu codigo:

```
public static List<Musica> lerMusica(List<Musica> listaMusica) throws NumberFormatException, ParseException, FileNotFoundException {
        String row;
        try {
            BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Joseilton/Desktop/verde/Verde/tmp/dataAEDs.csv"));
            String[] musicaParaCriar = new String[18];
            int contLinhas = 0;
            int cont = 0;
            while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] musica = row.split(",");
                if (contLinhas != 0) {
                    musicaParaCriar = musica;
                    Musica musicaCriada = criaMusica(musicaParaCriar);
                    listaMusica.add(musicaCriada);
                    cont++;
                }
                contLinhas += 1;
            }
            
            csvReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listaMusica;
    }
```

Se puder ajudar eu agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo usar nesses casos a classe scanner do java.util.Scanner;

// seu codigo antes do while

```
scanner = new Scanner(  row ).useDelimiter(",");
```

// ai vc acessa cada campo
`scanner.nextInt();`
// caso o valor seja inteiro

```
scanner.next();
```

// caso seja String

e outros tipos...